# dd/MM for Oct-Nov-Dec, other months dd/M - SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I'm current using SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM") which displays, for example, today's date as 18/04. But I don't want to display the zero before 4 i.e. I want it to be only 18/4. This I achieved by using SimpleDateFormat("dd/M").

My doubt is, what would be displayed for the months of Oct through Decemeber? I'm guessing it would truncate one digit and show only 1 for each of those months.

What I want is to be able to display two digits for those three months but omit the zero for all other months. Other than writing an if-then-else code block, is there a direct way to get this done?

Comment: Use Calendar to get the month(add one to the month, or make sure you know it starts at 0) and check if month >= 10(9 if you do not add one to it)

Comment: Change the date on your device / emulator to check :) I think it will be fine.

Comment: You will have no problem if you use "dd/M". I just tested it.

Comment: @KenWolf: Changed the date and checked. Indeed it works. Thanx LunarWatcher, Dejvid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By testing SimpleDateFormat("dd/M") with several months I've seen it behaves as you expect: Adding no zeros to 1 digit months but not cutting off 2 digit months. Here's an example with November:

```
@Test
public void shouldPrintNovemberWithTwoDigits() {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M");
    Date november = DateTime.now().plusMonths(6).toDate();
    String expectedDate = "18/10"; 

    String actualDate = simpleDateFormat.format(november);

    assertThat(actualDate, is(expectedDate));
}
```

And here's one with April (current month):

```
@Test
public void shouldPrintAprilWithOneDigit() {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M");
    Date april = DateTime.now().toDate();
    String expectedDate = "18/4";

    String actualDate = simpleDateFormat.format(april);

    assertThat(actualDate, is(expectedDate));
}
```

Both tests pass.. Try it out..